# how to solve such a browser compatibility issue?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I have a code that displays the text field as 3 boxes with hyphens in between. It runs fine in firefox, but in IE, the boxes are getting merged. What should I do?

```
    <div class="fileds-wrapper-left3">
                        <div class="fileds-inner" style="${promoterVO.pageConfig.promoterCodePart3.visibility}">
                            <div class="field-left">
                                <label><spring:message
                                        code="rmp.promoter.label.promoter_code" />:<sup class="error-msg">${promoterVO.pageConfig.promoterCodePart3.mandatory}</sup></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field-right">
                            <form:input path="promoterCodePart1" style="width:25px"/>-<form:input path="promoterCodePart2" style="width:40px"/>-<form:input path="promoterCodePart3" style="width:70px"/><form:errors path="promoterCodePart3" cssClass="error-field" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML.

Comment: <form:input are not valid html tags which is why you may be having styling issues. However I presume this code is from a source template file used for generating the actual html output. What does the generated html code look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use css reset

- http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

CSS Resets ensure that there is no default browser padding or margin, or anything else browser specific added to your styling.